Archimedean Langlands parameters from global Galois representations for $\mathrm{Sp}_{2n}$
$\DeclareMathOperator\Gal{Gal}\DeclareMathOperator\Sp{Sp}\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}\DeclareMathOperator\diag{diag}\DeclareMathOperator\antidiag{antidiag}\newcommand{\alg}{\mathrm{alg}}$Let $G$ be a split reductive group over $\mathbb Q$ with split Langlands dual group ${}^LG$ over $\mathbb Q$. Let $W_\mathbb R=\mathbb C^\times \cup j \mathbb C^\times$ be the Weil group of real numbers, where $j^2=-1$.
Choose a prime number $p$. Let $\rho: \Gal_{\mathbb Q} \to {}^LG(\mathbb Q_p^{\alg})$ be a continuous homomorphism. With suitable admissible assumptions on $\rho$, $\rho$ shall come from an automorphic representation of $G$ (see e.g. Conjecture 3.2.1. of Buzzard-Gee https://arxiv.org/abs/1009.0785). Nevertheless, there shall be an archimedean Langlands parameter $\rho_\infty : W_\mathbb R \to {}^LG(\mathbb Q_p^{\alg})$.
Le $S^1 \subseteq \mathbb C^\times \subseteq W_\mathbb R$ be the unit circle. Let $\mathbb R^\times \subseteq \mathbb C^\times$ be the subgroup of non-zero real numbers.
Question: how to construct $\rho_\infty$ from $\rho$? In particular, what is the type of $\rho_\infty |_{S^1}$? What is the type of $\rho_\infty |_{\mathbb R^\times}$ ?
Via archimedean Langlands correspondence, this question shall give shapes of (finitely many) irreducible $(g,K)$-modules $\pi_\infty$ attached to $\rho_\infty$.
Firstly, the image $\rho_\infty(j)$ shall be related to the image of $\rho(c)$ (up to conjugacy), where $c$ is a complex conjugation in $\mathbb \Gal_\mathbb Q$. See Lemma 2.3.2 in Buzzard-Gee https://arxiv.org/abs/1009.0785.
The case $G=\GL_2$ is fully understood. One may use the notion of Hodge-Tate weights (from $\rho|_{\Gal_{\mathbb Q_p}}$) in p-adic Hodge theory to read off the weights of $\rho_\infty$. And $\rho_\infty$ could be classified and written down explicitly.
Example: ($k \geq 1$) $\rho_\infty(re^{i\theta})=\diag \{e^{ki\theta}, e^{-ki\theta}\}$, $\rho_\infty(j)=\antidiag\{ 1, (-1)^k \}$ is related to certain Galois representation $\rho$ from holomorphic modular forms. The case of algebraic Maass forms is always understood (principal series).
Example: if $\rho=1$ is the trivial map, what is $\rho_\infty$?
I am mostly interested in explicit constructions in the case $G=Sp_{2n}$, where non-holomorphic discrete series $\pi_\infty$ may appear.
